Calculate transition probabilities
I have this data:
simulated_states = c("A", "E", "B", "B", "A", "C", "D", "A", "B", "D", "A", "D", 
"D", "E", "D", "D", "D", "E", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "C", "C", 
"D", "A", "A", "D", "A", "D", "A", "A", "A", "C", "C", "D", "A", 
"C", "C", "D", "E", "C", "C", "C", "E", "B", "A", "E", "E", "C", 
"C", "D", "E", "C", "E", "E", "A", "E", "B", "A", "A", "E", "E", 
"C", "E", "C", "C", "C", "D", "E", "D", "C", "D", "A", "B", "B", 
"E", "B", "A", "E", "C", "C", "D", "B", "B", "A", "C", "B", "A", 
"D", "A", "D", "E", "C", "D", "D", "A", "A", "C")

I know how to calculate transition probabilities :
calculate_transition_probs <- function(states) {
  
  transitions <- data.frame(
    from = states,
    to = c(states[-1], NA) 
  )
  
  transition_counts <- table(transitions, useNA = "always")
  transition_df <- as.data.frame(transition_counts)
  colnames(transition_df) <- c("from", "to", "count")
  transition_df <- transition_df[!is.na(transition_df$to), ]
  
  transition_df <- transition_df %>%
    group_by(from) %>%
    mutate(percent = count / sum(count) * 100) %>%
    ungroup()
  
  transition_df <- transition_df[, c("from", "to", "count", "percent")]
  transition_df <- transition_df[order(transition_df$from, transition_df$to), ]
  
  return(transition_df)
}

transition_probs <- calculate_transition_probs(simulated_states)

The result looks like this:
 from to count   percent
    A  A     7 26.923077
    A  B     3 11.538462
    A  C     6 23.076923
    A  D     5 19.230769
    A  E     5 19.230769
    B  A     7 58.333333
    B  B     3 25.000000
    B  C     0  0.000000
    B  D     1  8.333333
    B  E     1  8.333333
    C  A     0  0.000000
    C  B     1  4.545455
    C  C     9 40.909091
    C  D     9 40.909091
    C  E     3 13.636364
    D  A     9 42.857143
    D  B     1  4.761905
    D  C     1  4.761905
    D  D     4 19.047619
    D  E     6 28.571429
    E  A     2 11.111111
    E  B     4 22.222222
    E  C     7 38.888889
    E  D     2 11.111111
    E  E     3 16.666667

Now, I want to extend this to calculate transition probabilities for n-step probabilities.
E.g.

2 Steps: to = A given from = (A,A), to = A given from = (A,B), to = A given from =  (A,C) ..... to = B given from = (A,B), to = B given from = (B,B) etc.
3 Steps: to = A given from = (A,A,A), to = A given from = (A,B,A), etc.
N steps : to = A given from = (A,A,A...A) etc.

How can I write a function that does this for n-steps?
E.g. for 5 steps, the output should look like this:
 from1 from2 from3 from4 from5 to count percent
     A     A     A     A     A  A     0       0
     A     A     A     A     A  E     0       0
     A     A     A     A     A  B     0       0
     A     A     A     A     A  C     0       0
     A     A     A     A     A  D     0       0


It's not clear what you are asking. You start with mat, which looks very much your transition matrix (although you don't actually say this). This matrix tells you the probabilities of transitioning from one state to another. What you are simulating after that isn't clear to me and (I think) irrelevant. The 2-step transition matrix is simply mat %*% mat, which gives the probabilities of going from each current state to other states after 2 steps.

Hi Edward... I have simplified my question ... please see the edits

The first 4 elements are "A", "E", "B", "B". Does it mean "to = B given from = (A,E,B)" ?

imagine A = day1, e = day2, b= day3, b= day4... therefore, P(day4 = b given day3 = b, day2 = e, day1 = A)

Try the function below. I add another parameter step to control how many steps you want.

If you set step = 1, the output is the same as what you have done so far.
as.data.frame(stringsAsFactors = TRUE) + group_by(.drop = FALSE) is to prevent the missing combinations with 0 count from being excluding.
The code summarise(count = n(), .groups = "drop_last") indicates that the last level of grouping, i.e. the to column, will be dropped after counting each combination. This ensures that the subsequent mutate() computes conditional probabilities instead of overall probabilities.

calculate_transition_probs <- function(states, step = 1) {
  
  nc <- step+1
  lagged_mat <- matrix(
    states[sequence(rep(length(states), nc), 1:nc)],
    ncol = nc
  )
  
  trans_prob <- lagged_mat %>%
    as.data.frame(stringsAsFactors = TRUE) %>%
    head(-step) %>% 
    group_by(pick(everything()), .drop = FALSE) %>%
    summarise(count = n(), .groups = "drop_last") %>%
    mutate(percent = count / sum(count) * 100) %>%
    ungroup()
  
  names(trans_prob)[1:nc] <- c(paste0("from", 1:step), "to")
  return(trans_prob)
}

Result
calculate_transition_probs(simulated_states, step = 3)

# # A tibble: 625 × 6
#    from1 from2 from3 to    count percent
#    <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct> <int>   <dbl>
#  1 A     A     A     A         0       0
#  2 A     A     A     B         1      50
#  3 A     A     A     C         1      50
#  4 A     A     A     D         0       0
#  5 A     A     A     E         0       0
#  6 A     A     B     A         1     100
#  7 A     A     B     B         0       0
#  8 A     A     B     C         0       0
#  9 A     A     B     D         0       0
# 10 A     A     B     E         0       0
# # ℹ 615 more rows


Update
As per the comments from @Darren Tsai, an update is given as below
f <- function(dat, n = 1) {
  v <- unique(sort(dat))
  nms <- c(paste0("from", 1:n), "to")
  p <- aggregate(
    perc ~ .,
    cbind(
      setNames(as.data.frame(embed(dat, n + 1)[, (n + 1):1]), nms),
      perc = 1
    ), sum
  )
  q <- setNames(expand.grid(rep(list(v), n + 1)), nms)
  transform(
    merge(q, p, all = TRUE),
    perc = ave(ifelse(is.na(perc), 0, perc),
      ceiling(seq_along(to) / length(v)),
      FUN = \(x) x / sum(na.omit(x))
    )
  )
}

such that
> f(simulated_states, 1)
   from1 to       perc
1      A  A 0.26923077
2      A  B 0.11538462
3      A  C 0.23076923
4      A  D 0.19230769
5      A  E 0.19230769
6      B  A 0.58333333
7      B  B 0.25000000
8      B  C 0.00000000
9      B  D 0.08333333
10     B  E 0.08333333
11     C  A 0.00000000
12     C  B 0.04545455
13     C  C 0.40909091
14     C  D 0.40909091
15     C  E 0.13636364
16     D  A 0.42857143
17     D  B 0.04761905
18     D  C 0.04761905
19     D  D 0.19047619
20     D  E 0.28571429
21     E  A 0.11111111
22     E  B 0.22222222
23     E  C 0.38888889
24     E  D 0.11111111
25     E  E 0.16666667

> f(simulated_states, 2)
    from1 from2 to      perc
1       A     A  A 0.2857143
2       A     A  B 0.1428571
3       A     A  C 0.2857143
4       A     A  D 0.1428571
5       A     A  E 0.1428571
6       A     B  A 0.3333333
7       A     B  B 0.3333333
8       A     B  C 0.0000000
9       A     B  D 0.3333333
10      A     B  E 0.0000000
11      A     C  A 0.0000000
12      A     C  B 0.2000000
13      A     C  C 0.6000000
14      A     C  D 0.2000000
15      A     C  E 0.0000000
16      A     D  A 0.6000000
17      A     D  B 0.0000000
18      A     D  C 0.0000000
19      A     D  D 0.2000000
20      A     D  E 0.2000000
21      A     E  A 0.0000000
22      A     E  B 0.4000000
23      A     E  C 0.2000000
24      A     E  D 0.0000000
25      A     E  E 0.4000000
26      B     A  A 0.1428571
27      B     A  B 0.0000000
28      B     A  C 0.4285714
29      B     A  D 0.1428571
30      B     A  E 0.2857143
31      B     B  A 0.6666667
32      B     B  B 0.0000000
33      B     B  C 0.0000000
34      B     B  D 0.0000000
35      B     B  E 0.3333333
36      B     C  A       NaN
37      B     C  B       NaN
38      B     C  C       NaN
39      B     C  D       NaN
40      B     C  E       NaN
41      B     D  A 1.0000000
42      B     D  B 0.0000000
43      B     D  C 0.0000000
44      B     D  D 0.0000000
45      B     D  E 0.0000000
46      B     E  A 0.0000000
47      B     E  B 1.0000000
48      B     E  C 0.0000000
49      B     E  D 0.0000000
50      B     E  E 0.0000000
51      C     A  A       NaN
52      C     A  B       NaN
53      C     A  C       NaN
54      C     A  D       NaN
55      C     A  E       NaN
56      C     B  A 1.0000000
57      C     B  B 0.0000000
58      C     B  C 0.0000000
59      C     B  D 0.0000000
60      C     B  E 0.0000000
61      C     C  A 0.0000000
62      C     C  B 0.0000000
63      C     C  C 0.2222222
64      C     C  D 0.6666667
65      C     C  E 0.1111111
66      C     D  A 0.4444444
67      C     D  B 0.1111111
68      C     D  C 0.0000000
69      C     D  D 0.1111111
70      C     D  E 0.3333333
71      C     E  A 0.0000000
72      C     E  B 0.3333333
73      C     E  C 0.3333333
74      C     E  D 0.0000000
75      C     E  E 0.3333333
76      D     A  A 0.3333333
77      D     A  B 0.2222222
78      D     A  C 0.1111111
79      D     A  D 0.3333333
80      D     A  E 0.0000000
81      D     B  A 0.0000000
82      D     B  B 1.0000000
83      D     B  C 0.0000000
84      D     B  D 0.0000000
85      D     B  E 0.0000000
86      D     C  A 0.0000000
87      D     C  B 0.0000000
88      D     C  C 0.0000000
89      D     C  D 1.0000000
90      D     C  E 0.0000000
91      D     D  A 0.2500000
92      D     D  B 0.0000000
93      D     D  C 0.0000000
94      D     D  D 0.2500000
95      D     D  E 0.5000000
96      D     E  A 0.1666667
97      D     E  B 0.0000000
98      D     E  C 0.5000000
99      D     E  D 0.3333333
100     D     E  E 0.0000000
101     E     A  A 0.5000000
102     E     A  B 0.0000000
103     E     A  C 0.0000000
104     E     A  D 0.0000000
105     E     A  E 0.5000000
106     E     B  A 0.7500000
107     E     B  B 0.2500000
108     E     B  C 0.0000000
109     E     B  D 0.0000000
110     E     B  E 0.0000000
111     E     C  A 0.0000000
112     E     C  B 0.0000000
113     E     C  C 0.5714286
114     E     C  D 0.1428571
115     E     C  E 0.2857143
116     E     D  A 0.0000000
117     E     D  B 0.0000000
118     E     D  C 0.5000000
119     E     D  D 0.5000000
120     E     D  E 0.0000000
121     E     E  A 0.3333333
122     E     E  B 0.0000000
123     E     E  C 0.6666667
124     E     E  D 0.0000000
125     E     E  E 0.0000000


Older (Seems not OP wanted)
You can try the code below
f <- function(dat, n = 1) {
  from <- do.call(
    paste,
    c(asplit(as.matrix(embed(head(dat, -1), n)[, n:1]), 2),
      sep = "->"
    )
  )
  to <- tail(dat, -n)
  data.frame(from, to) %>%
    count(from, to, name = "perc") %>%
    mutate(perc = perc / sum(perc))
}

and you will obtain
> f(simulated_states, 1)
   from to       perc
1     A  A 0.07070707
2     A  B 0.03030303
3     A  C 0.06060606
4     A  D 0.05050505
5     A  E 0.05050505
6     B  A 0.07070707
7     B  B 0.03030303
8     B  D 0.01010101
9     B  E 0.01010101
10    C  B 0.01010101
11    C  C 0.09090909
12    C  D 0.09090909
13    C  E 0.03030303
14    D  A 0.09090909
15    D  B 0.01010101
16    D  C 0.01010101
17    D  D 0.04040404
18    D  E 0.06060606
19    E  A 0.02020202
20    E  B 0.04040404
21    E  C 0.07070707
22    E  D 0.02020202
23    E  E 0.03030303

> f(simulated_states, 2)
   from to       perc
1  A->A  A 0.02040816
2  A->A  B 0.01020408
3  A->A  C 0.02040816
4  A->A  D 0.01020408
5  A->A  E 0.01020408
6  A->B  A 0.01020408
7  A->B  B 0.01020408
8  A->B  D 0.01020408
9  A->C  B 0.01020408
10 A->C  C 0.03061224
11 A->C  D 0.01020408
12 A->D  A 0.03061224
13 A->D  D 0.01020408
14 A->D  E 0.01020408
15 A->E  B 0.02040816
16 A->E  C 0.01020408
17 A->E  E 0.02040816
18 B->A  A 0.01020408
19 B->A  C 0.03061224
20 B->A  D 0.01020408
21 B->A  E 0.02040816
22 B->B  A 0.02040816
23 B->B  E 0.01020408
24 B->D  A 0.01020408
25 B->E  B 0.01020408
26 C->B  A 0.01020408
27 C->C  C 0.02040816
28 C->C  D 0.06122449
29 C->C  E 0.01020408
30 C->D  A 0.04081633
31 C->D  B 0.01020408
32 C->D  D 0.01020408
33 C->D  E 0.03061224
34 C->E  B 0.01020408
35 C->E  C 0.01020408
36 C->E  E 0.01020408
37 D->A  A 0.03061224
38 D->A  B 0.02040816
39 D->A  C 0.01020408
40 D->A  D 0.03061224
41 D->B  B 0.01020408
42 D->C  D 0.01020408
43 D->D  A 0.01020408
44 D->D  D 0.01020408
45 D->D  E 0.02040816
46 D->E  A 0.01020408
47 D->E  C 0.03061224
48 D->E  D 0.02040816
49 E->A  A 0.01020408
50 E->A  E 0.01020408
51 E->B  A 0.03061224
52 E->B  B 0.01020408
53 E->C  C 0.04081633
54 E->C  D 0.01020408
55 E->C  E 0.02040816
56 E->D  C 0.01020408
57 E->D  D 0.01020408
58 E->E  A 0.01020408
59 E->E  C 0.02040816

> f(simulated_states, 3)
      from to       perc
1  A->A->A  B 0.01030928
2  A->A->A  C 0.01030928
3  A->A->B  A 0.01030928
4  A->A->C  C 0.01030928
5  A->A->D  A 0.01030928
6  A->A->E  E 0.01030928
7  A->B->A  C 0.01030928
8  A->B->B  E 0.01030928
9  A->B->D  A 0.01030928
10 A->C->B  A 0.01030928
11 A->C->C  D 0.03092784
12 A->C->D  A 0.01030928
13 A->D->A  A 0.01030928
14 A->D->A  D 0.02061856
15 A->D->D  E 0.01030928
16 A->D->E  C 0.01030928
17 A->E->B  A 0.01030928
18 A->E->B  B 0.01030928
19 A->E->C  C 0.01030928
20 A->E->E  C 0.02061856
21 B->A->A  E 0.01030928
22 B->A->C  B 0.01030928
23 B->A->C  C 0.01030928
24 B->A->C  D 0.01030928
25 B->A->D  A 0.01030928
26 B->A->E  C 0.01030928
27 B->A->E  E 0.01030928
28 B->B->A  C 0.02061856
29 B->B->E  B 0.01030928
30 B->D->A  D 0.01030928
31 B->E->B  A 0.01030928
32 C->B->A  D 0.01030928
33 C->C->C  D 0.01030928
34 C->C->C  E 0.01030928
35 C->C->D  A 0.02061856
36 C->C->D  B 0.01030928
37 C->C->D  E 0.03092784
38 C->C->E  B 0.01030928
39 C->D->A  A 0.01030928
40 C->D->A  B 0.02061856
41 C->D->A  C 0.01030928
42 C->D->B  B 0.01030928
43 C->D->D  A 0.01030928
44 C->D->E  C 0.02061856
45 C->D->E  D 0.01030928
46 C->E->B  A 0.01030928
47 C->E->C  C 0.01030928
48 C->E->E  A 0.01030928
49 D->A->A  A 0.01030928
50 D->A->A  C 0.01030928
51 D->A->A  D 0.01030928
52 D->A->B  B 0.01030928
53 D->A->B  D 0.01030928
54 D->A->C  C 0.01030928
55 D->A->D  A 0.01030928
56 D->A->D  D 0.01030928
57 D->A->D  E 0.01030928
58 D->B->B  A 0.01030928
59 D->C->D  A 0.01030928
60 D->D->A  A 0.01030928
61 D->D->D  E 0.01030928
62 D->D->E  A 0.01030928
63 D->D->E  D 0.01030928
64 D->E->A  A 0.01030928
65 D->E->C  C 0.01030928
66 D->E->C  D 0.01030928
67 D->E->C  E 0.01030928
68 D->E->D  C 0.01030928
69 D->E->D  D 0.01030928
70 E->A->A  A 0.01030928
71 E->A->E  B 0.01030928
72 E->B->A  A 0.01030928
73 E->B->A  E 0.02061856
74 E->B->B  A 0.01030928
75 E->C->C  C 0.02061856
76 E->C->C  D 0.02061856
77 E->C->D  D 0.01030928
78 E->C->E  C 0.01030928
79 E->C->E  E 0.01030928
80 E->D->C  D 0.01030928
81 E->D->D  D 0.01030928
82 E->E->A  E 0.01030928
83 E->E->C  C 0.01030928
84 E->E->C  E 0.01030928


It seems that OP requires the conditional probability, not overall probability. So the percentage must be sum up to 1 for every 5 rows.

@DarrenTsai Thanks for your comment. Now I updated my solution

Nice coding! You can get rid of the vexing ifelse() by doing (perc[is.na(perc)]=0). Does sum(na.omit(x)) add something here over sum(x, na.rm=TRUE)?

@Friede thank you. sum(na.omit(x)) does the same as sum(x, na.rm=TRUE)

Indexing using a convolution (convolve) will probably be most performant here. Using data.table:
library(data.table)

transprob <- function(x, steps) {
  s1 <- steps + 1L
  u <- sort(unique(x))
  m <- match(x, u)
  z <- length(u)^(0:steps)
  dt <- setcolorder(do.call(CJ, rep(list(u), s1)), s1:1)
  setnames(dt, c(paste0("from", 1:steps), "to"))
  i <- round(convolve(m - 1L, z, 1, "o")[s1:length(x)] + 1)
  a <- matrix(tabulate(i, nrow(dt)), z[s1])
  dt[,`:=`(count = c(a), percent = c(a/rowSums(a)))]
}

Demonstration 1:
transprob(simulated_states, 1L)[]
#> Key: <to, from1>
#>      from1     to count    percent
#>     <char> <char> <int>      <num>
#>  1:      A      A     7 0.26923077
#>  2:      B      A     7 0.58333333
#>  3:      C      A     0 0.00000000
#>  4:      D      A     9 0.42857143
#>  5:      E      A     2 0.11111111
#>  6:      A      B     3 0.11538462
#>  7:      B      B     3 0.25000000
#>  8:      C      B     1 0.04545455
#>  9:      D      B     1 0.04761905
#> 10:      E      B     4 0.22222222
#> 11:      A      C     6 0.23076923
#> 12:      B      C     0 0.00000000
#> 13:      C      C     9 0.40909091
#> 14:      D      C     1 0.04761905
#> 15:      E      C     7 0.38888889
#> 16:      A      D     5 0.19230769
#> 17:      B      D     1 0.08333333
#> 18:      C      D     9 0.40909091
#> 19:      D      D     4 0.19047619
#> 20:      E      D     2 0.11111111
#> 21:      A      E     5 0.19230769
#> 22:      B      E     1 0.08333333
#> 23:      C      E     3 0.13636364
#> 24:      D      E     6 0.28571429
#> 25:      E      E     3 0.16666667
#>      from1     to count    percent

Demonstration 2:
transprob(simulated_states, 2L)[]
#> Key: <to, from2, from1>
#>       from1  from2     to count   percent
#>      <char> <char> <char> <int>     <num>
#>   1:      A      A      A     2 0.2857143
#>   2:      B      A      A     1 0.1428571
#>   3:      C      A      A     0       NaN
#>   4:      D      A      A     3 0.3333333
#>   5:      E      A      A     1 0.5000000
#>  ---                                     
#> 121:      A      E      E     2 0.4000000
#> 122:      B      E      E     0 0.0000000
#> 123:      C      E      E     1 0.3333333
#> 124:      D      E      E     0 0.0000000
#> 125:      E      E      E     0 0.0000000

Demonstration 3:
transprob(simulated_states, 3L)[]
#> Key: <to, from3, from2, from1>
#>       from1  from2  from3     to count   percent
#>      <char> <char> <char> <char> <int>     <num>
#>   1:      A      A      A      A     0 0.0000000
#>   2:      B      A      A      A     0 0.0000000
#>   3:      C      A      A      A     0       NaN
#>   4:      D      A      A      A     1 0.3333333
#>   5:      E      A      A      A     1 1.0000000
#>  ---                                            
#> 621:      A      E      E      E     0 0.0000000
#> 622:      B      E      E      E     0       NaN
#> 623:      C      E      E      E     0 0.0000000
#> 624:      D      E      E      E     0       NaN
#> 625:      E      E      E      E     0       NaN


Benchmarking
Benchmarking against a couple of the other answers. Define the functions:
library(dplyr)

calculate_transition_probs <- function(states, step = 1) {
  nc <- step+1
  lagged_mat <- matrix(
    states[sequence(rep(length(states), nc), 1:nc)],
    ncol = nc
  )
  
  trans_prob <- lagged_mat %>%
    as.data.frame(stringsAsFactors = TRUE) %>%
    head(-step) %>% 
    group_by(pick(everything()), .drop = FALSE) %>%
    summarise(count = n(), .groups = "drop_last") %>%
    mutate(percent = count / sum(count) * 100) %>%
    ungroup()
  
  names(trans_prob)[1:nc] <- c(paste0("from", 1:step), "to")
  return(trans_prob)
}

f <- function(dat, n = 1) {
  v <- unique(sort(dat))
  nms <- c(paste0("from", 1:n), "to")
  p <- aggregate(
    perc ~ .,
    cbind(
      setNames(as.data.frame(embed(dat, n + 1)[, (n + 1):1]), nms),
      perc = 1
    ), sum
  )
  q <- setNames(expand.grid(rep(list(v), n + 1)), nms)
  transform(
    merge(q, p, all = TRUE),
    perc = ave(ifelse(is.na(perc), 0, perc),
               ceiling(seq_along(to) / length(v)),
               FUN = \(x) x / sum(na.omit(x))
    )
  )
}

Create a moderately sized vector.
x <- sample(LETTERS, 1e3, 1)

Benchmark 1:
steps = 1
bench::mark(
  DarrenTsai = calculate_transition_probs(x, steps),
  ThomasIsCoding = f(x, steps),
  jblood94 = transprob(x, steps),
  check = FALSE
)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 6
#>   expression          min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr>     <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 DarrenTsai       8.93ms   9.37ms      106.    4.03MB    31.4 
#> 2 ThomasIsCoding   6.75ms   7.13ms      140.    2.15MB     8.74
#> 3 jblood94        604.7µs 666.45µs     1466.  206.32KB    12.8

Benchmark 2:
steps = 2
bench::mark(
  DarrenTsai = calculate_transition_probs(x, steps),
  ThomasIsCoding = f(x, steps),
  jblood94 = transprob(x, steps),
  check = FALSE
)
#> Warning: Some expressions had a GC in every iteration; so filtering is
#> disabled.
#> # A tibble: 3 × 6
#>   expression          min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr>     <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 DarrenTsai      98.14ms  101.5ms      9.82    2.14MB    35.4 
#> 2 ThomasIsCoding  42.19ms  46.74ms     21.5    13.41MB     7.81
#> 3 jblood94         1.08ms   1.33ms    633.      1.06MB    24.0

Benchmark 3:
steps = 3
bench::mark(
  DarrenTsai = calculate_transition_probs(x, steps),
  ThomasIsCoding = f(x, steps),
  jblood94 = transprob(x, steps),
  check = FALSE
)
#> Warning: Some expressions had a GC in every iteration; so filtering is
#> disabled.
#> # A tibble: 3 × 6
#>   expression          min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr>     <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 DarrenTsai        3.09s    3.09s     0.324    48.8MB     5.50
#> 2 ThomasIsCoding    2.02s    2.02s     0.496   354.9MB     2.98
#> 3 jblood94        45.42ms  51.88ms    13.2      26.5MB    13.2


Your transition_counts can be converted to a transition matrix (I'll call it A for simplicty) by dividing the entries by their row sums:
A <- transition_counts / rowSums(transition_counts)

Then, the 2-step transition probabilities are simply
A %*% A
    to
from         A          B         C         D         E
   A 0.2435780 0.12229330 0.2404796 0.2137937 0.1798554
   B 0.3478582 0.15229446 0.1709910 0.1581451 0.1707112
   C 0.2169913 0.07974223 0.2398662 0.2642168 0.1991834
   D 0.2565411 0.13608217 0.2385630 0.1738936 0.1949202
   E 0.2256817 0.12838088 0.2548378 0.2386595 0.1524402

Note that the row sums still sum to 1. The 3-step is then
A %*% A %*% A

Or to simplify, we can use the expm package, which has the convenient %^% function:
library(expm)
A %^% 3

This function allows you to calculate the nth-step.
A %^% 10
    to
from         A         B         C         D         E
   A 0.2494011 0.1199961 0.2341925 0.2148659 0.1815444
   B 0.2494024 0.1199966 0.2341917 0.2148651 0.1815442
   C 0.2494006 0.1199957 0.2341927 0.2148664 0.1815446
   D 0.2494013 0.1199962 0.2341924 0.2148656 0.1815445
   E 0.2494010 0.1199962 0.2341926 0.2148660 0.1815442

The above is nearly steady state, which is given by solving:
qr.solve(rbind(t(A) - diag(5), rep(1, 5)), c(rep(0,5), 1))

#            A         B         C         D         E 
#    0.2494012 0.1199961 0.2341924 0.2148659 0.1815444


thanks edward! but I think maybe you might have overcomplicated this? I made an edit to the question to show how the final answer should look like ...maybe you can please take a look?

Yeah - you are right!  But what you want (a dataframe of all possible transitions) will be very long.

thank you for your guidance and feedback ... i guess its ok if n is small-ish? but ya, once n becomes too big, the number of rows will really increase ...

any idea how can I adapt your answer?

Sorry - I misunderstood what you wanted. Cheers!

Assuming you want to keep track of the intermediate states, assembling the lagged columns in a data frame, pasting the states together (using tidyverse::unite), and calling table should work:
library(dplyr) # for %>% operator
library(tidyverse) # for unite function
n = length(simulated_states)
data.frame(matrix(c(simulated_states[seq(1,n-2)],
                    simulated_states[seq(2,n-1)],
                    simulated_states[seq(3,n)]),
                  ncol=3)) %>% 
  {unite(data=.,col='d',names(.),sep='')} %>% table

As a function:
require(tidyverse)
calculate_transition_probs = function(states, m){
  n = length(states)
  lagged_states = c()
  for (i in 1:m){
    lagged_states = c(lagged_states, 
                      simulated_states[seq(i,n-m+i)])
  }
  return(data.frame(matrix(lagged_states,
                           ncol=m)) %>%
    {unite(data=.,col='d',names(.),sep='')} %>%
    table)
}


Hi njp, I tried running your first block of code but I got this error:

Error in n - 2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Sorry, n is the length of your vector. Updated.

thank you ... can you please show me how to use this function?
